# concatenate between elements of a list based on regex pattern

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a large character list with hundreds of elements coming from pdf documents. I am processing them so they are stored in a data frame with names in one column, the text elements in another.

I find the names are numbered and usually start a new page. I am matching a regex pattern for numbering and names and storing these into rows of a dataframe. I want to store the text between each names in the same row as the name that precedes these pages.

Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

text <- c("1. name Baramé stuff more stuff" ,"more stuff", "more stuff", 
      "2. name  D'orsons stuff more stuff", "more stuff more stuff", 
      "3. name Bar-son stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff", 
      "4. name lastname stuff", "more stuff more stuff", "more stuff")
```

This gives a list with [1:9] elements

I process this in a data frame matching the numbered names:

```
doc <- data_frame("name" = str_extract(text, 
                                   "^\\d+\\.\\s+([\\w\\. -'-]+)\\s+\(+[A-Z]+[0-9]+\)"), 
              "page" = str_detect(text, "^\\d+\\.\\s+([\\w\\. -'-]+)\\s+\(+[A-Z]+[0-9]+\)"),
              "sep" = unlist(strsplit(text, "^\\d+\\.\\s+([\\w\\. -'-]+)\\s+\(+[A-Z]+[0-9]+\)")))
```

I cant figure out the last step where the rows containing the text elements (pages) in between the numbered names are all concatenated into a row. Basically all text after "1. name lastname" and before "2. name lastname" goes into a variable "text" and so on for the other numbered names.

So in the end, the dataframe has the same number of rows as the number of names and the text is in a column with that name (text in between names goes to preceding name).

```
name                text
1. name Baramé    stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
2. name D'orsons    stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
3. name Bar-son    stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff 
4. name lastname    stuff more stuff more stuff
```

I hope I have described this clearly enough.

Edit: I have modified the example to be more representative of last name variations with the actual regex I am using.

Comment: Please provide a more representative example.  Is the `lastname` constant in all?  It is not clear whether there is any variation in the number of words in last name

Comment: Based on the text provided `i1 <- grepl("^\\d+", text);
v1 <- sapply(split(text, cumsum(i1)), function(x) paste(x, collapse=" "));
read.csv(text=sub("^(\\S+\\s+\\S+)(\\s+.*)", "\\1,\\2", v1), header = FALSE, col.names = c("name", "text"))`

Comment: I should have used the actual pattern I have: so here is the regex I am using: "^\\d+\\.\\s+([\\w\\. -'-]+)\\s+\(+[A-Z]+[0-9]+\)"

Comment: In your new example, there is only word for lastname.  If you keep on changing, then we have to change code all the time.  Please include all the patterns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the pattern showed, we can create a grouping variable from the occurrence of numbers at the start of the string, use that to `paste` the contents and then `separate` the column into two

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(name = text, grp = cumsum(grepl("^\\d+", text)) )%>%
     group_by(grp) %>% 
     summarise(name = paste(name, collapse=" ")) %>% 
     select(-grp) %>%
     extract(name, into = c("name", "text"),
                     "^(\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+)\\s+(.*)")
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  name             text                                  
#  <chr>            <chr>                                 
#1 1. name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
#2 2. name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
#3 3. name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
#4 4. name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
txt <- aggregate(name ~ grp, data.frame(name = text, 
   grp = cumsum(grepl("^\\d+", text))), FUN = paste, collapse=" ")[[2]]
txt1 <-  sub("(^(?:(\\S+\\s+){2})\\S+)", "\\1,", txt)
read.csv(text = txt1, header = FALSE, col.names = c("name", "text"))
#            name                                    text
#1 1. name lastname  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
#2 2. name lastname  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
#3 3. name lastname  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
#4 4. name lastname  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
```

#### Update

With the updated example, change the `sub` to

```
txt1 <- sub("(^(?:([^ ]+\\s+){2})[^ ]+)", "\\1,", txt)
read.csv(text = txt1, header = FALSE, col.names = c("name", "text"))
#               name                                    text
#1    1. name Baramé  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
#2 2. name  D'orsons  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
#3   3. name Bar-son  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
#4  4. name lastname  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
```

Or in the `tidyverse` approach

```
tibble(name = text, grp = cumsum(grepl("^\\d+", text)) )%>%
      group_by(grp) %>% 
      summarise(name = paste(name, collapse=" ")) %>% 
      select(-grp) %>%
      extract(name, into = c("name", "text"),
                  "^([^ ]+\\s+[^ ]+\\s+[^ ]+)\\s+(.*)")
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  name              text                                  
#  <chr>             <chr>                                 
#1 1. name Baramé    stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
#2 2. name  D'orsons stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
#3 3. name Bar-son   stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
#4 4. name lastname  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
```

Comment: Akrun, the names are not consistent, the actual regex I am using is this: "^\\d+\\.\\s+([\\w\\. -'-]+)\\s+\\(+[A-Z]+[0-9]+\\)"

Comment: @Monduiz  Updated the post based on your new example

Comment: Can you adapt the tidy example? This is going to work!

Comment: @Monduiz  Updated the tidy approach

Comment: Thank you! The cumsum(grepl()) is brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

To separate each record you can take the cumulative sum of whether a number is present in the given element, and subset based on that.

```
nums <- cumsum(grepl('[0-9]', text))
out <- sapply(seq(max(nums)), function(x) paste(text[nums == x], collapse = ' '))
out
# [1] "1. name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff"
# [2] "2. name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff"
# [3] "3. name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff"
# [4] "4. name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff"
```

To separate the names from the rest of the record, you can use `word` from `stringr` to extract the first three words.

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(name = word(out, 1, 3), stuff = word(out, 4, -1))
#               name                                  stuff
# 1 1. name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
# 2 2. name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
# 3 3. name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
# 4 4. name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
```

or, if you want to get rid of the numbers

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(name = word(out, 2, 3),
           stuff = word(out, 4, -1))
#            name                                  stuff
# 1 name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
# 2 name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
# 3 name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
# 4 name lastname stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data.frame(text,stringsAsFactors = F)%>%
   group_by(s= cumsum(grepl("^\\d+",text)))%>%
   summarise(new=paste(text,collapse = " "))%>%
   mutate(new=sub("((?:\\S+\\s+){3})","\\1:",new))%>%
   do(read.table(text=.$new,sep=":",col.names = c("name","text")))
              name                                   text
1 1. name lastname  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
2 2. name lastname  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
3 3. name lastname  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
4 4. name lastname  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
```

In Base R:

```
s=tapply(text,cumsum(grepl("^\\d+",text)),paste,collapse=" ")
read.table(text=sub("(^(?:\\S+\\s+){3})","\\1:",s),sep=":",col.names = c("name","text"))
               name                                   text
1 1. name lastname  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
2 2. name lastname  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
3 3. name lastname  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
4 4. name lastname  stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff
```